# UML Use case for vending machine

Tags: uml, use-case

I am new to UML and I need some help with identifying actors and use cases for a simple scenario. I have to model a vending machine. I can't decide on the set of actors and use cases and I would really appreciate some help. The way I would model it is to have Customer actor, Switchboard actor and Vending machine. The customer's use cases are insert coins, select product, cancel order, collect change. The Switchboard use cases are set timer (the user has some time to select a product, after that the process is canceled). Finally, the Vending machine use cases are find a product, check money balance, dispense, return change. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

From vending machine point of view, the only usecase is Sell Item (or Sell Product). Because of usecase model defines use full services provided by modeled system in collaboration with actors (Actor is external to the system). Actions insert coin, find product etc. are just steps of procedure, which define behavior of vending machine within Sell Item usecase execution. It means, usecase model will be simple. useCase "Sell Item" connected to actor "Customer". Switchboard is part of vending machine and is involved to internal processes execution.